# Installing and Debugging Sample Lead Web Services project for Dynamics GP 2016

Tags: web-services, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

I am trying to install and Debug a sample web services project for Dynamics GP, which is installed with web services SDK. [This Manual](https://dynamicsstarter.files.wordpress.com/2011/09/wsprogrammersguide.pdf) have project steps and code for testing the sample lead web service. I am trying to build InstallLeadSecurityMetadata project and getting below error on config file, no idea how can I solve it. I am not a .Net developer and not have any good concept about the .Net programming.

> Warning   1   The 'configSource' attribute is not allowed.     C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Dynamics\GPWebServicesSDK\v16\Samples\LeadWebService\LeadWebService\InstallLeadSecurityMetadata\
>   InstallLeadSecurityMetadata\app.config    7   15  InstallLeadSecurityMetadata
>
> Warning 2      The 'bindingConfiguration' attribute is invalid - The
>   value 'DiscoveryServiceBindingHttp' is invalid according to its
>   datatype 'serviceBindingConfigurationType' - The Enumeration
>   constraint failed.    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Dynamics\GPWebServicesSDK\v16\Samples\LeadWebService
>   \LeadWebService\InstallLeadSecurityMetadata\InstallLeadSecurityMetadata\app.config    9   91  InstallLeadSecurityMetadata

Comment: Going to be real straightforward with you here so don't take it personally. Stay away from the GP Web Services. Too many times I've been burned. Unless you like reinstalling the entire thing on a regular basis (monthly?) to resolve errors like this one, just to find out that the web services lack critical features (they do), then by all means continue down this path. If you do keep going, then I would recommend reinstalling and make sure you *tediously* and *meticulously* follow the instructions exactly. Just note that those instructions are 7 years old and chances are they never get updated.

Comment: Infact I also felt so, and thinking about custom web service.